# Hosting hidden service

Tags: onion-services, windows, web-hosting

I am trying to set up my own hidden service. My last problem with torrc file has been sorted, I still have another problem. Website is not loading on tor, at all. It is accessible via Chrome at 127.0.0.1 and at localhost. I have forwarded port 80 and still no result. Anyone have a clue what might be the most common problem? 
I am using latest Savant.

According to the comment the `torrc` contains the following lines:

```
# Hidden Service 
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\Name\tor_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts from your `torrc`.

Comment: All I have is that:

# Hidden Service
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\Name\tor_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include these lines there.

Comment: *"I have forwarded port 80"* <-- If you mean in your router, then you should not need to do that. It will make your service accessible from the internet.

Comment: I'm not on my Tor machine at the moment so I'm going by memory. To view your site in the Tor Browser using 127.0.0.1 you need to disable the SOCKS proxy for that address. Typing in your .onion address should display your site without any changes to your settings.